# How to add values to DataGridColumn dynamically in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

In the project I am working in there is webpage which retrieve data from the database. So I have used DataGrid show my data.
But sometimes I wanted to add more columns to the DataGrid.That means I want to add some columns with data dynamically.
However I have new columns addition to the DataGrid and here is my code.

```
DataGridColumn myCol = new BoundColumn();
myCol.HeaderText = "Test";
myCol.Visible = true;
grdHeiskort.Columns.Add(myCol);
```

In here "grdHeiskort" is DataGrid ID.
Now I want to add the data to this column named="test".That data is gain from the database.Suppose I am retrieving dataset from DB and I want to add the data in 1st column in dataset to my "test" column.So how can I do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a BoundColumn you can set the name of the DataField to whatever the name of the field you want it to be from your dataset:

```
BoundColumn myCol = new BoundColumn();
myCol.HeaderText = "Test";
myCol.Visible = true;
myCol.DataField = "NameOfYourDataColumn";
grdHeiskort.Columns.Add(myCol);
```

Comment: Ok.Thank you.Can you tell me how to add Text Field to this column?